# How to trigger an alert once receiving push notifications using Broadcast notifications?

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

Using MobileFirst Platform 6.3,
I am implementing the `sendMessage` API from `WL.Server` for pushing notification to all devices (`Push.ALL`).

The notification is successfully pushed into the device but it doesn't trigger an alert like NotifyAllDevice (as can be seen in the sample project for push notifications).

What can I do to trigger a dialog box with the message inside it, after the notification has arrived to my device?

```
function sendMessage(msg){
    var notificationOptions = {};
    notificationOptions.type = 0;
    notificationOptions.message = {};
    notificationOptions.message.alert = msg;
    notificationOptions.target = {};
    notificationOptions.target.platform = ['G','A'];

    // set notification properties for GCM
    notificationOptions.settings = {};
    notificationOptions.settings.gcm = {};
    notificationOptions.settings.gcm.sound = "default";

    // set notification properties for APNS
    notificationOptions.settings.apns = {};
    notificationOptions.settings.apns.sound = "default";

    //WL.Server.notifyAllDevices(userSubscription, notification);
    WL.Server.sendMessage("PushNotifications", notificationOptions);

    return { 
        result: "Notification sent to user :: " 
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For broadcast / tag based messages, the notifications are received on the client / app. in the callback

```
WL.Client.Push.onMessage(props, payload)
```

More info. on the API is found at - 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Client.Push.html%23onMessage

Here's how you would define the callback and display an in the app:

```
WL.Client.Push.onMessage = function(props, payload) {
    alert("broadcastReceived invoked");
    alert("props :: " + JSON.stringify(props));
    alert("payload :: " + JSON.stringify(payload));
};
```